# The value "<" is not valid in an attribute on PasswordBox control

Tags: wpf, xaml, passwordbox

While creating a WPF application which includes a `PasswordBox` control, I tried to set the `PasswordChar` to display '<' instead of '*'. I wrote the following code:

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="<"></PasswordBox>
```

When using this code, the following error is reported:

> Error  1   The value "<" is not valid in an attribute.

Comment: I might have up-voted this question if you had showed the error message that you were receiving.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="&lt;"></PasswordBox>
```

You'll find a comprehensive list of symbols and how to write them in XAML in this MSDN article: 
[XML Character Entities and XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748250(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

`<` is a special character in XML. You need to use `&lt;`, as in:

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="&lt;" />
```

or set it in code.

**XAML**

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="tbPassword" />
```

**Code**

```
tbPassword.PasswordChar = '<';
```

Answer (score 2):

'<' is a reserved character, try using this instead:

```
<PasswordBox PasswordChar="&lt;"></PasswordBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `&lt;` for < and `&gt;` for > in xaml:

```
 <PasswordBox PasswordChar="&lt;"></PasswordBox>
```